# Cubes in $R^n$ and distributions over cubes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am reading a classic cs theory paper. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/2005-Efficient_Algorithms_for_Online_Decision_Problems.pdf

I am not sure about some math. First of all there is a lemma :
*For any v $\in R^n$, the cubes $[0,\frac{1}{\epsilon}]^n$ and v+ $[0,\frac{1}{\epsilon}]^n$ overlap in at least a $(1-\epsilon|v|_1)$ fraction.*

I am trying to decode first of all what *a " $[0,\frac{1}{\epsilon}]^n$ cube*" is. An estimation:

- It is a n-dimensional cube with side length $1/\epsilon$

Now there is also this sentence "x and y are both distributions over cubes". **Now what is a distribution over a cube?**  An estimation:

- We will call d a distribution over cube $[a, b]^n$ , a distribution over the $2^n$ corner points of the cube? Or all the points of cube?

Any answers are welcome, also any reading suggestions if it does not require any extreme background.

Comment: I don't see why $[0,\frac1\epsilon]^n$ shouldn't be the same as what it is with the standard notation (the cartesian product of $n$ copies of $[0,\frac1\epsilon]$). I wouldn't necessarily call it a *cube*, but I can see that "hypercube" or "$n$-dimensional cube" seem unnecessarily wordy.